# Handilng url named group on CreateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I need to catch the parameter from URL named group in my class-based view that extends CreateView.

In URL, I pass the name of the model, using one class-based view to create any of the object types.

```
url(r'^(?P<modelname>\w+)/create/$', GenericCreate.as_view()),
```

view:

```
class GenericCreate(CreateView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        for app in ['foo', 'bar']:
            self.mdlnm_model = models.get_model(app, self.modelname)
            if self.mdlnm_model:
                break

        formcls = get_form_class(self.modelname)

        template_name = 'create/' + self.modelname + '_create.html'
        try:
            get_template(template_name)
        except TemplateDoesNotExist:
            template_name = 'create.html'

        self.form_class = formcls
        self.model = self.mdlnm_model
        self.template_name = template_name
        self.sucess_url = "/%s/" % (self.modelname,),

        super(CreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GenericCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context.update({
            'title': self.model._meta.verbose_name,
            'creation': True,
            'icon': self.modelname + '.png'
        })
        return context
```

How can I get the URL named group 'modelname' and assign it to self.modelname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you get any URL parameters in a class-based view:

```
self.modelname = self.kwargs['modelname']
```

But you absolutely can't do this in `__init__`. That method is called well before any request is present, and generally should not be overridden in a CBV. You should probably be doing this in `get_context_data`.

Comment: Yes, my problem was passing the nodelname and setting it on a class. Had to edit a dispatch method in order to do that. Overriding `__init__` was not a smart idea, as you said. Thanks.